# How to get the single return value from mysql stored function in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want return the last inserted id using the following function:
MySql Stored Function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `set_user`( user_id int(11), u_name varchar(50),              
                                                      pass  varchar(128)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE newest_id INT(11);

INSERT INTO `test_db`.`users`
(`id`,`user_name`,`password`)
VALUES (user_id, u_name, pass);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO newest_id FROM test_db.users;

RETURN newest_id;
END
```

And here is the php code:

```
$sp = "select test_db.set_user(1, 'uname', 'pass123')";

$res = $con->multi_query( $sp );
if( $res ) {
  $results = 0;

    if ($result = $con->store_result()) {
      printf( "<b>Result #%u</b>:<br/>", ++$results );
      while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo $row["newest_id"];
      }
      $result->close();

    }

}
```

the function is successfully inserts the data But php is not getting the single return value. Please help.

Comment: echo mysqli_insert_id($con);

Comment: instead of doing through stored procedure, just use `mysqli_insert_id($con)` to get the last inserted id. Very easy and native function

Comment: Also you said:- `the function is successfully inserts the data `-> which function?I am unable to see any function in your code.2.i am unable to see any data insertion code also.

Comment: @AlivetoDie This function test_db.set_user(1, 'uname', 'pass123') Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `multi_query()` for a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked you function it's all good but need some changes to work perfectly , so check these points:-
1. Add a **LIMIT 1** on select statement for LAST_INSERT_ID as **LAST_INSERT_ID()** return multiple rows with same LAST_INSERT_ID.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `set_user`( user_id int(11), u_name varchar(50),              
                                                      pass  varchar(128)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE newest_id INT(11);
INSERT INTO `test_db`.`users`
(`id`,`user_name`,`password`)
VALUES (user_id, u_name, pass);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO newest_id FROM test_db.users LIMIT 1;

RETURN newest_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

2. Then add the **alias** `"newest_id"` in select query in PHP.

   `$sp = "select test_db.set_user(1, 'uname', 'pass123') as newest_id";
   $res = $con->multi_query( $sp );
   if( $res ) {
     $results = 0;
       if ($result = $con->store_result()) {
         printf( "<b>Result #%u</b>:<br/>", ++$results );
         while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
           echo $row["newest_id"];
         }
         $result->close();
       }
   }`

   I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the alias `newest_id` to the result of your `SELECT`:

```
$sp = "select test_db.set_user(1, 'uname', 'pass123') AS newest_id";
```

The variable inside the procedure is not visible outside it, and doesn't become the name of the column returned by the `SELECT`.